# How to handle Http 403.14 error for MVC application hosting with Godaddy plesk

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, shared-hosting

I recently published the asp.net mvc app on Godaddy server.and it is saying HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

and when i enable the directory browsing ,instead of rendering Home/index as first page ,the directory list started showing.

I am new to Godaddy hosting and in MVC, setting a static start page doesn't make any sence.